# A quick question about factorials

Tags: factorial

So I'd like to write a function like this using factorials:

f(x) = (x-1)(x-2)

so that when I plug in x = 2 I get f(x) = 0.

I tried this:

f(x) = (x-1)!/(x-3)!
which as I understand evaulates to (x-1)(x-2).

But plugging in x = 2 to that equation gives 1!/(-1!) which doesn't exist really.

What's the issue here? Is it with the conversion from f(x) = (x-1)!/(x-3)! to (x-1)(x-2)?

What I'd really like to do in the big picture is write a series that will put out (x-1) for the first term, (x-1)(x-2) for the second term, (x-1)(x-2)(x-3) for the third, and so on. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that (at least originally speaking), the factorial is only defined for nonnegative integers - so the manipulation you've used is only valid if $x \in \{3, 4, \dots\}$. One can regard the [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) as an extension of the factorial function to real (or even complex) values, and this computation can be formalized (using the fact that $\Gamma(z) = (z - 1)!$) as

$$\frac{\Gamma(z)}{\Gamma(z - 2)}$$

Now the fact that $\Gamma(z - 2)$ has poles at $z = 1$ and $z = 2$ is why we have zeros at $1$ and $2$ in the factored expression.

As a remark, note that the poles of $\Gamma(z)$ at the negative integers will offset the poles of $\Gamma(z - 2)$ except at the particular points $z = 1, 2$. So by analytic continuation, we really can regard the expressions as equal for all complex numbers, by suitable definition at the poles of $\Gamma(z - 2)$.

Comment: Thank you! Can I clarify something quickly? Does this mean that plugging 1 or 2 into the function you've described for me above will evaluate to 0? Or will it only evaluate to 0 in the factored expression?

Comment: If you have a pole of a function in the denominator, without any cancellation in the numerator, then you can analytically extend the function across that point with the value of $0$. So technically, $\Gamma(1) / \Gamma(-1)$ makes no sense, but we can define it to be $0$.

Comment: If the downvoter would care to offer a suggestion or improvement, I'd greatly appreciate it.